# Is there an equivalent of `puma-dev` in Phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to run my development server under custom domain and subdomain, ex.: `https://api.custom.local/`. In `Rails` I would use `puma-dev`, is there an equivalent of this tool in `Phoenix`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've followed Justin [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56857640/11194039) and made a little research on `puma-dev`.

We can use `puma-dev` as reverse proxy for Phoenix app.

## Prerequisites

Follow `puma-dev` [README](https://github.com/puma/puma-dev) in order to install it.

## Phoenix endpoint development configuration

```
url: [
  sheme: "https",
  host: "api.custom.test"
],
https: [
  port: 443,
  cipher_suite: :strong,
  keyfile: System.get_env("SSL_KEYFILE_PATH"),
  certfile: System.get_env("SSL_CERTFILE_PATH")
]
```

## Result

We can access `https://api.custom.test`

## Note

`puma-dev` allows to add custom domains by executing `puma-dev -install -d local`

Answer (score 1):

Edit your `config/dev.exs` file. Chave the configuration of `MyApp.Endpoint`. You will want to add or edit the `:url` key. You can do something like the following

```
url: [host: "api.custom.local", port: 4000]
```

Then you can just start your application as your normally would.